Derivative of a functional related to the gradient
Let $\pmb{\sigma}=(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$ where $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ are the Pauli matrices, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\,
\sigma_2= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix},\,
\sigma_3= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and consider the functional
$$
J\colon C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C}^2)\to\mathbb{R},\quad J(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}|\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla\phi|^2\,dx
$$
I am trying to compute it's Fréchet derivative. To do this i am trying to compute
$$
\frac{d}{d\,\epsilon}J(\phi+\epsilon\phi)|_{\epsilon =0}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\frac{d}{d\,\epsilon}|\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla(\phi+\epsilon\phi)|^2|_{\epsilon =0}\,dx
$$
Now
$$
\frac{d}{d\,\epsilon}|\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla(\phi+\epsilon\phi)|^2=2\,|\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla(\phi+\epsilon\phi)|\frac{\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla(\phi+\epsilon\phi)}{|\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla(\phi+\epsilon\phi)|}\,\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\left(\nabla (\phi+\epsilon\phi)\right)
$$
and here is where i am blocked. Any help is appreciated.
Edit: I did some computation. As suggested in the comment, I consider
$$
J(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla\phi)\overline{(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla\phi)}\,dx
$$
Then
$$
\frac{d}{d\,\epsilon}J(\phi+\epsilon\psi)|_{\epsilon =0}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\frac{d}{d\,\epsilon}(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla (\phi+\epsilon\psi))\overline{(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla (\phi+\epsilon\psi))}|_{\epsilon =0}\,dx
$$
and I get that
$$
J'(\phi)[\psi]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\left[(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla\phi)\overline{(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla\psi)}+(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla\psi)\overline{(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla\phi)}\right]\,dx
$$
Is it right? Is there a way to simplify it?

Shouldn't it be another function than $\phi$ together with $\epsilon$ ? Also, you should rewrite $J$ as a scalar product in order to take advantage of its bilinearity.

Thanks for the comment! So I should write $$J(\phi+\epsilon\psi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}(\nabla (\phi+\epsilon\psi))\cdot(\nabla (\phi+\epsilon\psi)),dx$$
and carry on the computations?

Yes, except that one factor should be complex-conjugated (because $|z|^2 = \bar{z}z$). Then you will get a quadratic polynomial in $\epsilon$ after distributing all the terms.

@Abezhiko I've edited the question, could you please have a look at it?

Your computations are correct. You may simplify the final result a little bit further by using the facts that 1° the operator $A = \sigma\cdot\nabla$ is hermitian (as discussed in your previous post) and 2° the inner product of $J[\phi] = \langle A\phi,A\phi \rangle$ is conjugated-symmetric, hence $J' = 2\operatorname{Re}\langle A^2\phi,\psi\rangle$.
